# Alternate way for union to improve SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, union, case

Please help me find another solution/block of code to get the same result but avoiding UNION.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT EQPID, "EVENTVAL" AS "EVENTVAL", SUM("20120501") AS "20120501", SUM("20120502") AS "20120502", SUM("20120503") AS "20120503", SUM("201204") AS "201204", SUM("201205") AS "201205"
FROM
(
SELECT EQPID, "EVENTVAL" AS "EVENTVAL", SUM("20120501") AS "20120501", SUM("20120502") AS "20120502", SUM("20120503") AS "20120503", SUM("201204") AS "201204", SUM("201205") AS "201205"
FROM
(
    SELECT EQPID,
            CASE
            WHEN EQPID LIKE 'MS-%'
            THEN 'TKINQTY'
            END AS "EVENTVAL",

            CASE 
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE = '20120501' 
            THEN SUM(QTY)
            END AS "20120501",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE = '20120502'
            THEN SUM(QTY)
            END AS "20120502",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE = '20120503'
            THEN SUM(QTY)
            END AS "20120503",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120430'
            THEN SUM(QTY)
            END AS "201204",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120501' AND '20120530'
            THEN SUM(QTY)
            END AS "201205"

    FROM
    (
        SELECT CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID, SUM(TKINQTY) QTY
        FROM DAILY_DATA
        WHERE CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120530'
        AND EQPID LIKE 'MS-%'
        GROUP BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID
        ORDER BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID
    )
    GROUP BY EQPID, CUTOFF_DATE
)
GROUP BY EVENTVAL, EQPID
UNION
SELECT EQPID, "EVENTVAL" AS "EVENTVAL", SUM("20120501") AS "20120501", SUM("20120502") AS "20120502", SUM("20120503") AS "20120503",SUM("201204") AS "201204", SUM("201205") AS "201205"
FROM
(
    SELECT EQPID,
            CASE
            WHEN EQPID LIKE 'MS-%'
            THEN 'TKOUTQTY'
            END AS "EVENTVAL",

            CASE 
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE = '20120501' 
            THEN SUM(QTYO)
            END AS "20120501",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE = '20120502'
            THEN SUM(QTYO)
            END AS "20120502",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE = '20120503'
            THEN SUM(QTYO)
            END AS "20120503",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120430'
            THEN SUM(QTYO)
            END AS "201204",

            CASE
            WHEN CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120501' AND '20120530'
            THEN SUM(QTYO)
            END AS "201205"

    FROM
    (
        SELECT CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID, SUM(TKOUTQTY) QTYO
        FROM DAILY_DATA
        WHERE CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120530'
        AND EQPID LIKE 'MS-%'
        GROUP BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID
        ORDER BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID
    )
    GROUP BY EQPID, CUTOFF_DATE
)
GROUP BY EVENTVAL, EQPID
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(EVENTVAL, EQPID)
ORDER BY EQPID, EVENTVAL
```

**Result:**

```
EQPID | EVENTVAL | 20120501 | 20120502 | 20120503 | 201204 | 201205
____________________________________________________________________

MS-A1 | TKINQTY  | 21528 |   28386 | 18288 | 821295 | 908602

MS-A1 | TKOUTQTY  | 21510 |   28359 | 18720 | 820470 | 907320

MS-B1 | TKINQTY  | 21530 |   28456 | 18852 | 821560 | 908564

AND SO ON....
```

Assuming that I would add another value in eventval column, like TKQTY, I would have to use another UNION statement and I don't want to do that. Can you please help me find another solution for this? I have search all over but can't find answer. Please help. thanks a lot.

Comment: I would suggest that you describe what you want to do, providing sample input date and desired results.  Your query is quite hard to follow.

Comment: I have edited by post and included a sample result. Thanks for the advice @GordonLinoff. I have a table name daily_data, with columns: Cutoff_date, EQPID, TKINTQY, TKOUTQTY.. I group the same values in cutoff_date and eqpid then get the sum of tkinqty and tkoutqty. then uses case and union to get the result above.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is too long.. If my understanding right,you can place 'union' in the subquery.
like this:

```
SELECT EVENTVAL, EQPID,CASE WHEN..,CASE WHEN..
FROM (
SELECT CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID, SUM(TKOUTQTY) QTYO,'TKOUTQTY' AS EVENTVAL
        FROM DAILY_DATA
        WHERE CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120530'
        AND EQPID LIKE 'MS-%'
        GROUP BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID
UNION
SELECT CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID, SUM(TKINQTY) QTYO,'TKINQTY' AS EVENTVAL
        FROM DAILY_DATA
        WHERE CUTOFF_DATE BETWEEN '20120401' AND '20120530'
        AND EQPID LIKE 'MS-%'
        GROUP BY CUTOFF_DATE, EQPID
UNION
..)
GROUP BY EVENTVAL, EQPID
```